# How to configure access to Yandex Disk with GUI?

Tags: indicator, ubuntu-mate, caja, online-storage

I'm using Ubuntu MATE 18.04 LTS and want to set Yandex.Disk (cloud storage web-service like Google Drive) here to be accessed from GUI.

How should I do this?

Comment: You might add some info about Yandex.Disk, what is it, and why you/we would want/need it. Also, any good reason to still run 18.04?

Comment: @heynnema Ubuntu version does not matter, really. Yandex.Disk is a alternative for Google Drive. Method below works for all versions from 14.04 LTS (ESM) to 20.04 LTS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## 1. Installation of CLI daemon

First of all we need to download CLI-based official Yandex.Disk client from their repository:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://repo.yandex.ru/yandex-disk/yandex-disk_latest_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./yandex-disk_latest_amd64.deb
```

Note: the commands above will add the corresponding APT repository to the system to keep Yandex.Disk updated.

For authorization from terminal run `yandex-disk token username` (where *username* is your actual username) command and follow its instructions.

## 2. Installation of GUI indicator

Then to have GUI indicator we need to add [special PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Eslytomcat/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) to the system:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:slytomcat/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install yd-tools
```

Finally we can launch the *Yandex.Disk Indicator* from *Applications*→*Internet* menu and follow steps of the wizard. Sometimes wizard need to run twice.

The wizard will create `~/Yandex.Disk` folder (default) and will launch indicator in the tray to inform user about updates and to communicate with daemon:

[image: Yandex.Disk Indicator]

---

## (*) Accessing Yandex.Disk from file manager

For systems without special Yandex.Disk client we have to use Caja file-manager:

1. Create application-based password on the corresponding page of [Yandex.Passport](https://passport.yandex.ru/profile/access)
2. Open Caja, select *Connect to Server* and set:

   - *Server* → `webdav.yandex.ru`;
   - *Type* → *Secure WebDAV (HTTPS)*
   - provide *Username* (without domain) and application-based *Password*

   and click *Connect*.

   Note: optionally: you can use it directly by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> and writing `davs://webdav.yandex.ru` in the location bar and provide *username* with application-based *password*.